# Visual Studio Team Explorer sync and pull error

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I am trying to push my change code to a VSTS git repository. When I am trying to sync, I get an error in my output window

> Git failed with a fatal error. ArgumentNullException encountered.
>   Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path From
>   https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.visualstudio.com/_git/xxxxxxxxxxxxx  =
>   [up to date]      master     -> origin/master

but the code is successfully pushed to my VSTS repository
And this error only comes when I tried to pull on VSTS

Comment: restart the visual studio application & try pull again

Comment: Do you meet the error message for `git pull` every time? And what if you execute `git pull` manually?

Comment: @Umang I tried it much time it is the same error

Comment: @Marina Liu - MSFT 
yes in git console there is the same error while having PULL But (PUSH is working correctly on both visual studio VSTS and git Console)

Comment: @AmitSinghRawat what version of VS are you running? According to https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues/1119 , you need to add username and email.

Comment: vs 2017 community latest version

Comment: According to https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues/1119 , you need to add username and email. 

git config --global user.name "blah"
git config --global user.email "blah"

Comment: @Umang is this command I have to use in GIT CONSOLE git config --global user.name "blah" git config --global user.email "blah"

Comment: @Umang and having VS community 2017 v 15.7 I think

Comment: Yes, In command prompt Or Git Console, Please enter following commands respectively: 1)  git config --global user.name "your username" 2)  git config --global user.email "youremailaddress@blah.com"

Comment: ok thanks, I will follow this instruction I and get in touch with you later

Comment: @AmitSinghRawat please make sure the repo URL is same for git fetch and push, you can check in VS team explorer -> Settings -> repository settings -> check the fetch and push URL for the remote.

Comment: @AmitSinghRawat Can you pull without error in VS now?

Comment: hello @Marina Liu - MSFT yes URL is same in fetch and push

Comment: hello @Umang using your command now I am able to pull using GIT CMD 

but the situation is same as previous in VS Team Explorer
Same error on pull 

Git failed with a fatal error.
ArgumentNullException encountered.
   Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path
From https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/_git/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 = [up to date]      master     -> origin/master

Comment: @AmitSinghRawat Has you double check the username and email address in VS same as what you set by cmd. The way to check in VS as: VS -> team explorer -> Settings -> Global settings.

Comment: @AmitSinghRawat May I please request you to upgrade git for windows (https://git-scm.com/download/win) & see if that resolve the issue?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: using latest git for windows but the error is same as before in VS Team Explore
and thinging to Uninstall All git software and then Install again then try 
let See what will Happen